# OpenMP tasks don't see changes of shared variables

Tags: c++, gcc, task, openmp, memory-model

I start two OpenMP tasks that simply print the value of a shared variable initially set to 1. I change the variable between starting the two tasks to 2.

I'd expect both tasks to see the changed value of the variable, that is the output should be `2 2`. However I always get `1 2` or `2 1`, which is the result I'd expect if the variable was firstprivate.

I also tried to set a lock before starting the tasks and unset it after they are registered and the variable is changed. Also made both tasks wait for the lock to ensure the variable has already changed. The result is the same, I’m not getting both tasks to see the changed value of the variable (2 2). What am I getting wrong? Using GCC 7.4.0. `omp_get_num_threads` returns 8.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    omp_lock_t lock;
    int i = 1;
    omp_init_lock(&lock);
    #pragma omp parallel default(shared) shared(i)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            omp_set_lock(&lock); // set lock before any tasks are registered
            #pragma omp task default(shared) shared(i)
            {
                omp_set_lock(&lock); // should wait until lock is unset and i is 2?
                std::cout << i;
                omp_unset_lock(&lock);
            }
            i = 2;
            #pragma omp task default(shared) shared(i)
            {
                omp_set_lock(&lock);
                std::cout << i;
                omp_unset_lock(&lock);
            }
            omp_unset_lock(&lock); // unset lock after i is set to 2
        }
    }
    omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit.** Maybe `i` is not stored in shared memory for some reason? If I change it to something that can't be stored in a register, or make it global, or even just print it's address (`std::cout << &i;`), the program works as expected. Possibly undefined behaviour or a GCC issue?

Answer (score 3):

First, expecting ordering on `shared` dependencies is just asking for race conditions. Please don’t do this − this is just a thought exercise so you understand what is happening. In any real code, use dependencies that enforce the proper flow of data between tasks with dependencies.

#### Expected behaviour

The expected sequence of events is:

- enter omp single
- create task 1
- set i=2
- create task 2
- reach end of parallel region, now waiting for tasks to finalize
- (possibly on a different thread/core) task 1 executes: read i
- (possibly on a different thread/core) task 2 executes: read i
- tasks have finished, program terminates

#### Current behaviour

However tasks *may* have a delayed execution, and you’re only guaranteed that it will happen before the end of your current parallel region, so you can not really read it as if it were a sequential program. Tasks *may* also ave an *undeferred* execution, that is be run immediately with the main task being suspended. This is typically a decent choice if the tasks are very small or if there are no more threads available.

From the OpenMP 4.8 spec:

> **undeferred task**
>
> A task for which execution is not deferred with respect to its generating task region.
>   That is, its generating task region is suspended until execution of the undeferred task is completed.

Thus what is happening is most probably:

- enter omp single
- create task 1
- suspend parent task to execute task 1 *undeferred*
- set i=2
- suspend parent task to execute task 2 *undeferred*
- program terminates

#### How to fix it

Instead, you should run tasks when the data they need is ready:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
        #pragma omp task depend(in:i)
        {
            std::cout << 'a' << i;
        }

        #pragma omp task depend(out:i)
        i = 2;

        #pragma omp task depend(in:i)
        {
            std::cout << 'b' << i;
        }

        #pragma omp task depend(in:i)
        {
            std::cout << 'c' << i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should always return `a1c2b2` or `a1b2c2`. Note that I say *should* because writing to stdout is not really atomic either, so I theoretically can’t exclude the occasional `abc122` or something like that.

The tasks 3 and 4 only run once the task 2 is done, and ensure that the data is properly forwarded.

#### How *not* to fix it

Creating locks that will suspend the child tasks, restoring the parent task, will only complicate things.

The sequence of events then becomes:

- enter omp single
- acquire lock in generating task
- create task 1
- suspend parent task to execute task 1 *undeferred*
- suspend task 1 waiting for lock
- restore generating task
- set i=2
- suspend parent task to execute task 2 *undeferred*
- suspend task 2 waiting for lock
- restore generating task
- release lock in generating task
- restore task 1, acquire lock, print 1, release lock
- restore task 2, acquire lock, print 2, release lock
- program terminates

The locks don’t affect `i`, they just suspend the child tasks until the end of the generating task. Some form of memory barrier/flush would probably fix that, and you’ll also need to stop the compiler from reordering the access to `i` with respect to the lock acquiring and releasing. The easiest way to achieve this is to make `i` an atomic int:

(please don’t use this code)

```
int main()
{
    omp_lock_t lock;
    omp_init_lock(&lock);
    std::atomic<int> i(1);

    #pragma omp parallel shared(i)
    #pragma omp single
    {
        omp_set_lock(&lock);
        #pragma omp task shared(i)
        {
            // enter task, then suspend until i = 2
            omp_set_lock(&lock);
            std::cout << i;
            omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }

        i = 2;

        #pragma omp task shared(i)
        {
            // enter task, then suspend until i = 2
            omp_set_lock(&lock);
            std::cout << i;
            omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }

        // unset lock after i is set to 2 and child tasks are created
        // child tasks are possibly started and suspended at this point
        omp_unset_lock(&lock);
    }

    omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, that is the wrong approach, using thread-parallelism constructs on task-parallelism programs. **Expecting ordering on `shared` dependencies is just asking for race conditions.** Plus you’re creating tasks to suspend them immediately, which makes no sense.

With `volatile int i`, let’s look at the following task’s assembly (from gcc’s output with `-S -fverbose-asm`) (lines with `###` are my comments):

```
#pragma omp task shared(i)
{
    // enter task, then suspend until i = 2
    omp_set_lock(&lock);
    __asm__ volatile("mfence":::"memory");
    std::cout << i;
    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}
```

```
.LFB2346:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA2346
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp   #,

### get "omp_data_i", a struct containing _the value of i_ and the lock id
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp) # .omp_data_i, .omp_data_i

### get i, store it on the stack at -4
# lock+volatile.cc:15:         #pragma omp task shared(i)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax # .omp_data_i, tmp86
    movl    8(%rax), %eax   # .omp_data_i_2(D)->i, i.6_3
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  # i.6_3, i

### get the lock id and call omp_set_lock
# lock+volatile.cc:18:             omp_set_lock(&lock);
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax # .omp_data_i, tmp87
    movq    (%rax), %rax    # .omp_data_i_2(D)->lock, _5
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # _5,
    call    omp_set_lock    #

### our manually written assembly
# lock+volatile.cc:20:             __asm__ volatile("mfence":::"memory");
#APP
# 20 "lock+volatile.cc" 1
    mfence  
# 0 "" 2

### get i from the stack and call cout
# lock+volatile.cc:21:             std::cout << i;
#NO_APP
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # i, i.0_9
    movl    %eax, %esi  # i.0_9,
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi    #,
    call    _ZNSolsEi   #

### get the lock and call unset_lock
# lock+volatile.cc:22:             omp_unset_lock(&lock);
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax # .omp_data_i, tmp88
    movq    (%rax), %rax    # .omp_data_i_2(D)->lock, _11
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # _11,
    call    omp_unset_lock  #
```

With `int i` (non-volatile), let’s now look at this task’s assembly:

```
#pragma omp task shared(i)
{
    // enter task, then suspend until i = 2
    omp_set_lock(&lock);
    std::cout << __atomic_load_n(&i, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}
```

```
.LFB2346:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA2346
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp   #,

### get "omp_data_i", a struct containing _the address of i_ and the lock id
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)  # .omp_data_i, .omp_data_i

### get the lock id and call omp_set_lock
# lock+volatile.cc:18:             omp_set_lock(&lock);
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # .omp_data_i, tmp87
    movq    (%rax), %rax    # .omp_data_i_2(D)->lock, _3
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # _3,
    call    omp_set_lock    #

### get i and call cout
# lock+volatile.cc:19:             std::cout << __atomic_load_n(&i, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # .omp_data_i, tmp88
    movq    8(%rax), %rax   # .omp_data_i_2(D)->i, _6
    movl    (%rax), %eax    #* _6, _9
    movl    %eax, %esi  # _10,
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi    #,
    call    _ZNSolsEi   #

### get the lock id and call unset_lock
# lock+volatile.cc:20:             omp_unset_lock(&lock);
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # .omp_data_i, tmp89
    movq    (%rax), %rax    # .omp_data_i_2(D)->lock, _12
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # _12,
    call    omp_unset_lock  #
```

As you can see, in the first case, getting the value of `i` in the register is performed before the `omp_set_lock` call. Only using atomic (even with relaxed consistency) have I managed to move it to the “expected” place, presumably because then the access can not be reordered with respect to the lock.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Indeed, as the variables are shared I'd except the value of i is read at the time of task execution, which happens after I've set i to 2. So I'm expecting to see 2 2 as the output. But I see 1 2 or 2 1 as if I was using firstprivate.

Comment: I'm getting 8 threads, though the same happens if I change the thread count.

Comment: BTW, the code is non-conforming.  If one of the tasks is executed by the same thread that also executes the single construct, the code violates OpenMP semantics of locks. Although, this rarely happens it's a potential race condition.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm Only if the same task owns it, rather than the same thread, I think. The OpenMP spec says (section 3.3.4 `omp_set_lock` and `omp_set_nest_lock`, in Constraints on Arguments: “A simple lock accessed by omp_set_lock that is in the locked state must not be owned by the task that contains the call or deadlock will result.”)

Comment: About undeferred tasks: I didn't know about this, especially about the deadlock handling you described. Still, that doesn't seem to explain why task one prints 1. "Release lock in generating task" (omp_unset_lock) implies a flush, so task one should see 2.

The solution with `std::atomic` works, but so does `struct { int v; } i` with `i.v`s. So it doesn't seem to be an atomicity problem.

Comment: Thank you for presenting a better solution. I'm aware that the original code is bad practice, and I wouldn't normally write code like that. But I'm still interested in the reason it fails, which I haven't found (or understood correctly based on your answer) yet.

Comment: @user1768761 Looked at the assembly and it’s as I expected: when the task is started, and before it is suspended, `i` is moved to a register. Just use atomics, or better, execute tasks when data is ready through dependencies.

Comment: @Cimbali, indeed, that's what I was expecting too. What still bothers me is that the implicit fushes in the program should make the view of `i` consistent to all threads, but they don't. (Explicit flushes don't help either.) [Here](https://youtu.be/Q96sRpbKzEs?t=673) and [here](https://users.fit.cvut.cz/~soch/mi-par/openmp/vice9.html) it's explicitly stated that variables in a thread's temporary view that are stored in registers should be synchronized with memory.

Comment: @user1768761 The generating thread is correctly making its view of `i` consistent to all threads. The tricky part is to convince the compiler that `i` can change during the `set_lock`, because he does not see it as a memory reference. If you make it a `volatile int *` (emphasis on the pointer) the flushes do what you expect.

Comment: @Cimbali: ok, still one more thing, sorry. Shouldn't a `#pragma omp flush` after `omp_set_lock`s work too? Based on the docs the flush should finish by the next access to the variable. So the temporary view of `i` is invalidated and the register should be updated from memory on the next access, I presume? Yes, volatile works, and so does a non-effective line `&i;` anywhere in the program. The point is to discourage the compiler from storing it in a register.

Comment: @user1768761 I think `omp_set_lock` implies a flush as well, so the code _should_ work as far as I understand it. Maybe the compiler is wrongly optimizing it away? Could be because it is a stack variable, never accessed as a pointer. Furthermore the default data sharing is `shared` so maybe respecting this is a whole lot of overhead? In any case it’s not the sort of behaviour I would want to rely on. Flushes are very expensive, and higher-level constructs that are meant for parallel programming (dependencies, atomics) are easier to reason about.

Comment: @Cimbali Yes, I'm a bit afraid of claiming I have found a compiler bug. I have always been proven wrong so far. But no other explanations I've seen seems to be satisfying.

Comment: @user1768761 Let’s see what they anwser: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92672

Comment: @Cimbali Oh, thanks I'm interested too. Tested with the latest dev GCC and the result is the same. One more thought: `omp_unset_lock` in the generating task indeed implies a flush, however I'm not sure when this flush is required to complete as `i` is possibly not accessed after it by the same thread. Anyway, adding additional accesses doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Thanks, I see their answer about a possible deadlock. But I'm not experiencing deadlocks... Is deadlock undefined behaviour? Maybe because of this clause?
"The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following: terminate; make a call to a library I/O function; perform an access through a volatile glvalue; or perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation."